# working of exponential operator ** in Python

Tags: python, pow

I am running a python script where I am computing following:

```
t - 2 ** (j - 1) * l
```

Where `t = 302536`, `j = 6`, `l = 0`.

This returns me `302536` (`t`), I am not able to understand how. As per me the result should have been `302535` (`t - 1`).

`2 ** (j - 1) * l` results in 0 which according to me should have resulted in 1 as `(j - 1) * l` results in 0.

How is this being computed?

Comment: Why pandas? Can you explain it?

Comment: this is just a line of code. All other computation in the script require pandas. May be I should have written python only

Comment: I think you can check [`operator-precedence`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) - first is evaluate `()`, then `**` and last `*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that binds tighter than power is parentheses. Python (and every other language that natively supports a power operator that I've seen) follows arithmetic convention on this one, so you don't need to memorize different sets of conflicting rules. You operation can be explicitly rewritten as follows:

```
t - ((2 ** (j - 1)) * l)
```

As you pointed out, setting `l = 0` discards much of the computation. It's just that it discards everything but `t` itself.

You could make such things explicit by using the function form of the power operator. Any of the following imports would work for the example below:

```
from math import pow
from operator import pow
from operator import __pow__ as pow
from numpy import pow
```

It seems like you wanted/expected

```
t - pow(2, (j - 1) * l)
```

But instead got

```
t - pow(2, j - 1) * l
```